# How to centre Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

Currently updating my website and have run into a problem that I can't find a working solution to.

The problem is to do with positioning my nav bar, at the moment it is below some JavaScript and on the left edge of the page, I would like it to be directly below the Java Script and centred, the css followed by the html is below:

```
ul {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 50%
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

And the html:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.about.trinity-international.com">About</a></li>  
<li><a href="http://www.contact.trinity-international.com">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Here is a link to the subdomain I'm currently using to test it on:
http://www.beta.trinity-international.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you missed a **;** after **top: 50%**.

1) Remove **position: absolute;**

2) Change width of ul to something like 400px (For Test)

3) Add: margin: 0 auto; to ul

Comment: No Problem. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the styling within `ul { }` and in the `li` swap `float: left;` for `display: inline-block;` it will align in the middle.

I suggest refraining from taking elements out of the flow of the document via absolute positioning where ever possible.